# when data loader fetchs next batch, loader wouldn`t run my function in _getitem_

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am running 3D medical Segmentation, and the training image size is different from the label. so I write a convert function to make the size the same. this function in *getitem()* (data loader get data).
Dataloader doesn't have any problems fetching data from the first batch, but it doesn't execute the convert function I wrote in *getitem* when it first starts fetching data from the second batch. I would like to ask what is the problem and how should I solve it?

**here is error information**(batch_size==3)

```
Epoch 1/200
---------------
yes it has runned here
torch.Size([609, 512, 256])
torch.Size([473, 512, 256])
change image shape torch.Size([609, 512, 256])
change label shape torch.Size([609, 512, 256])
--------------------------------------
yes it has runned here
torch.Size([546, 512, 256])
torch.Size([536, 512, 256])
change image shape torch.Size([546, 512, 256])
change label shape torch.Size([546, 512, 256])
--------------------------------------
yes it has runned here
torch.Size([576, 512, 256])
torch.Size([535, 512, 256])
change image shape torch.Size([576, 512, 256])
change label shape torch.Size([576, 512, 256])
--------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TrainModel.py", line 330, in <module>
    main(train_param)
  File "TrainModel.py", line 323, in main
    trained_model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, data_loader, param)
  File "TrainModel.py", line 151, in train_model
    for inputs, targets in data_loader[phase]:
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/liangxijie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 56, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [609, 512, 256] at entry 0 and [546, 512, 256] at entry 1
```

**getitem()** code:

```
print('yes it has runned here')
        itk_img = sitk.ReadImage(self.image_files[item])
        itk_lbl = sitk.ReadImage(self.label_files[item])
        #print(itk_img, itk_lbl)
        #image = np.fromfile(itk_img,self.data_type)
        image = convert_from_Image_to_tensor(itk_img)
        label = convert_from_Image_to_tensor(itk_lbl)
        print(image.shape)
        print(label.shape)
        image,label = change_image(image,label)
        print("change image shape",image.shape)
        print("change label shape",label.shape)
        print("--------------------------------------")
        #print("np_array size:",image.shape)
        #label = np.fromfile(itk.lbl,self.data_type)
        return self.prepare_data(image, label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your images are of different sizes, causing the tensors to also be of different sizes. You can't train a model with tensors of different sizes. You can do this with torchvision [transforms](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html). Not sure if you're already trying to do this in one of the other functions you didn't give the code for.

Comment: transforms can only modify 2d images, right? and in terms of size, I chose to fill it with 0.

Comment: i do not understand which parts of  code do you need?